# How to ADD UNIQUE with a value from a table referenced by ID (i.e., join)?

Tags: sql, mariadb

My database has two tables relevant to my question:

• `process` with columns `title` and `project_id` (and many more)
• `project` with columns `id` and `client_id` (and many more)

I would like to `ADD UNIQUE` on `title` AND `client_id`.

Example: process contains a record with title "LoremIpsum" and project_id 4. Project 4 refers to client_id 2 (unique = ["LoremIpsum", 2]). Adding another record with title "LoremIpsum" and project_id 11 should not be possible, given that project 11 refers to client_id 2 as well (unique = ["LoremIpsum", 2], too). Adding another record with title "LoremIpsum" and project_id 8 should be possible, given that project 8 refers to client_id 5 (unique = ["LoremIpsum", 5]).

**Is it possible to ADD UNIQUE on a value from a table by foreign key reference?**

Pseudocode:

```sql
ALTER TABLE process
   ADD UNIQUE UN_title_x_client (title,
       `SELECT client_id FROM JOIN project WHERE project.id = process.project_id`);
```

Comment: No, not using a constraint. However, a trigger can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to prevent any two processes with the same title to be connected to the same client. Or other way around: A client must not be connected to two (or more) processes with the same title.

So you need a `UNIQUE KEY` on `(client_id, title)`, but there is no table which contains both columns. But you can have a process to contain a copy of the `client_id` from the linked project and make it part of the foreign key. Then you can define a `UNIQUE KEY` on `process(client_id, title)`.

The schema for `process` table could look like this:

```
create table process(
  id int primary key,
  title varchar(255),
  project_id int,
  client_id int,
  -- other columns
  foreign key (client_id, project_id)
    references project(client_id, project_id)
    on update cascade on delete cascade,
  unique key (client_id, title)
);
```

You will have to copy the `client_id` in your `INSERT` statements though. But updates can be maintained by the system.